# How can I select an element and the text that follows it with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to find a class within a sentence and wrap it along with remainder of the text in the sentence.

What I want:

```html
<div class="container">
  text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
  text text text text text text text text <div class="newWrap"><div class="test">TEST</div> text
  text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text</div>
</div>
```

One of the many efforts I've tried:

```js
$('.test').each(function() {
  $(this).nextUntil('div').addBack().wrap('<div class="newWrap"></div>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="containter">
    text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
    text text text text text text text text <div class="test">TEST</div> text
    text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
</div>
```

Comment: Note that I corrected missing closing quotes on the outer class in both code blocks.

Answer (score 0):

### Get next sibling Node

No need to use jQuery. in pure JavaScript:

- Use [Node.nextSibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nextSibling) to get the next sibling Node
- Use [Document.createElement()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) to create a new Element
- Use [Element.append()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/append) to append Nodes to a desired Element

```js
// DOM Utility functions:

const EL = (sel, par) => (par || document).querySelector(sel);
const ELNew = (tag, prop) => Object.assign(document.createElement(tag), prop);

// Task:

const EL_test = EL(".test");
const ND_next = EL_test.nextSibling;
const EL_newWrap = ELNew("div", {className: "newWrap"});

EL_newWrap.append(EL_test, ND_next);
EL(".containter").append(EL_newWrap);
```

```css
div { padding: 10px; outline: 1px solid red; }
.newWrap { background: gold; }
```

```html
<div class="containter">
  aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa
  <div class="test">TEST</div>
  bbbb bbbb bbbb bbbb bbbb bbbb
</div>
```

**Notice:**

As per requirement the above will only target the **first Node sibling**, so if you have other elements like `<br>` etc, it will not work as expected. So read furhther.

### Get all next sibling Nodes

A `while` loop would be necessary in order to reach the end of the parent container and **get all the next siblings**.
In such case the target `.test` element should be [prepended](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/prepend) last (after the while loop):

```js
// DOM Utility functions:

const EL = (sel, par) => (par || document).querySelector(sel);
const ELNew = (tag, prop) => Object.assign(document.createElement(tag), prop);

// Task:

const EL_test = EL(".test");
const EL_newWrap = ELNew("div", {className: "newWrap"});

while(EL_test.nextSibling) EL_newWrap.append(EL_test.nextSibling);
EL_newWrap.prepend(EL_test);
EL(".containter").append(EL_newWrap);
```

```css
div { padding: 10px; outline: 1px solid red;}
.newWrap { background: gold; }
```

```html
<div class="containter">
  aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa
  <div class="test">TEST</div>
  bbbb <i>bbbb</i> <span>bbbb</span> bbbb <br> bbbb <b>bbbb</b>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the text is always at the end, this seems to work.

```js
$('.test').each(function() {
  const thisEl = $(this);
  const content = thisEl.parent().contents();
  const text = content[content.length - 1];
  $(text).add(thisEl).wrapAll('<div class="pink">');
});
```

```css
.container {
  border-top: 2px solid #ccc;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.pink {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  before before before before before before before before before before before
  <div class="test">TEST</div> after after after after after after after after
</div>

<div class="container">
  before before before before before before before before before before before
  <div class="other">between between</div>
  <div class="test">TEST</div> after after after after after after after after
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="other">way before</div>
  before before before before before before before before before before before
  <div class="other">between between</div>
  <div class="test">TEST</div> after after after after after after after after
</div>
```

Comment: `content[content.length - 1]` can give false positives